# SQL Server stored procedure hashes differently in C# to Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I am calling a stored procedure to create and hash a new password. It is being called from a .NET/C# WebAPI controller.

```
_sqlDataContext.ExecuteCommand("[Users].[SetNewPassword]", new List<SqlParameter>
{
       new SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) { Value = user.Id },
       new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256) { Value = command.Password }
});
```

`userId` and `command.Password` are a GUID and simple string respectively.

The stored procedure being called hashes and stores the password as follows:

```sql
ALTER PROC [Users].[SetNewPassword]
    @UserId uniqueidentifier,
    @Password NVARCHAR(256) -- Unsalted and unhashed
AS
    BEGIN TRANSACTION [Transaction1]
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @PasswordSalt uniqueidentifier = NEWID();
        DECLARE @SaltedPassword binary(64);

        SET @SaltedPassword = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @Password + CAST(@PasswordSalt as NVARCHAR(256)));

        -- Insert new password
        INSERT INTO Passwords  (UserId, Password, PasswordSalt, UpdatedDate) 
        VALUES (@UserId, @SaltedPassword, @PasswordSalt, GETDATE());

        COMMIT TRANSACTION [Transaction1]
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Transaction1]
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
```

When I call this from the WebAPI / C# method, I get a different hash than when I execute the stored procedure directly in SQL Server Management Studio.

Furthermore, if I execute the `SetPassword` stored procedure from C#, the following stored procedure - `ValidatePassword` - to validate a password fails.

This is because the hash stored in the database does not match the hash being generated by `ValidatePassword`

```sql
ALTER PROC [Users].[ValidatePassword]
    @UserId uniqueidentifier,
    @Password NVARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PasswordHash binary(64) = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', (SELECT @Password +  CAST((SELECT p.PasswordSalt FROM Passwords p WHERE p.UserId = @UserId) AS NVARCHAR(256))))

    SELECT 
        CASE 
           WHEN EXISTS (SELECT UserId
                        FROM Passwords
                        WHERE UserId = @UserId
                          AND Password = @PasswordHash)
              THEN 1 
              ELSE 0
        END

    SELECT @passwordHash;
END
```

Question / problem:

Why is the hash generated by the stored procedure when called from C# different to the one generated from within SQL Server Management Studio? Is there is an issue with unicode/binary conversion or something like that?

Please note I appreciate that 'rolling your own' authorisation is not always a good idea, but this is addressing a temporary issue with a legacy app.

Comment: Interesting. Just to confirm - you're saying the hash it generates (without the salt) is different depending on where the stored procedure is executed from?

Comment: Seems to be.  Wondered if it was a text encoding issue or similar.

Comment: Have you tried a different algorithm, like MD5?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on my SQL server. I've tried both Md5 and sha2_512: SSMS: `select cast(hashbytes('sha2_512','foo') as uniqueidentifier)` = `6EBAFBF7-3606-90F8-E56F-BBF3283E524C` and linq: `var res = db.ExecuteQuery<Guid>("select cast(hashbytes('sha2_512','foo') as uniqueidentifier)");`  = `6ebafbf7-3606-90f8-e56f-bbf3283e524c`